# In a dynamic form add a "Remove" button and send all the input value to laravel controller to store in db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 7. Here I am using a dynamic form there clicking on "Add More" I can add same type of input fields. I want to add a remove button beside the new row to remove the new row which is add by click on "Add More" button. Also Clicking on "Submit" Button I want to send the data to controller to store it in DataBase.

My blade part:

```
 <div class="card-body">
               
               <div class="div-repeat-notification" style="display: none;">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Name :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cn_name[]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
                          </div> 
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Email :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cn_email[]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
                          </div> 
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Phone :</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cn_phone[]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone"/>
                          </div> 
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      
                      <a style="float:right;color:#fff;" class="div-repeat-notification_add_more btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="addMore('.div-repeat-notification')">Add More</a>

              </div>
```

my js part:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div-repeat-notification_add_more').before($('.div-repeat-notification').html());
    
  })
  function addMore(vr){
    var html = $(vr).html();
    //$(vr+'_add_more').before(html);
    $(vr+'_add_more').before('<div class="div-repeat-notification">'+html+'</div>');
  }
```

this is adding row dynamically. I want a remove button beside new row . and submit button to send data to the controller. Note: I am not using any model.

Comment: where is your problem!?

Comment: I mentioned in the last line.  I want a remove button beside new row . and submit button to send data to the controller.

Comment: use form repeater for that